# Five-symmetry of closed arcs in Penrose tiling; proof?

Tags: reference-request, tiling

In the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling) for the Penrose tiling, the following is mentioned:

> Conway and Penrose proved that whenever the colored curves on the P2 or P3 tilings close in a loop, the region within the loop has pentagonal symmetry, and furthermore, in any tiling, there are at most two such curves of each color that do not close up.[36]

Unfortunately, the reference is to a Martin Gardner article that provides no proof, so I'm curious as to what the proof here is.

Comment: Just download the book **Penrose Tiles to Trapdoor Ciphers, Cambridge University Press**

Comment: That is the Martin Gardner article that provides no proof.

Comment: Branko Grünbaum and Geoffrey Shephard's "*Tilings and Patterns*" may be a helpful source. Especially, around page $543$. If you open a free account you can borrow the book at https://archive.org/details/isbn_0716711931/page/542/mode/2up

Comment: Okay that looks promising.

Comment: ...it leaves a proof as an exercise.  Does say that it can be based on making the closed curves smaller and smaller through composition though.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to come back to this and I've come up with a proper proof.  It requires a few important lemmata and points of clarification:

Firstly, there are three types of loops to care about; I'll use the colors and descriptions on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_tiling) as best I can.

1. The red loops in the P2 (kite-and-dart) tiling.  These make a $6\pi/5$-radian turn on darts and a $2\pi/5$-radian turn on kites.
2. The green loops in the P2 tiling.  These make a $2\pi/5$-radian turn on both darts and kites.
3. The pink loops in the P3 (rhombus) tiling.  These make a $2\pi/5$-radian turn on thick rhombi and a $4\pi/5$-radian turn on thin rhombi.

The blue loops in the P3 tiling seem like they would be relevant, but they can actually never enclose more than a single vertex.

Next, it's worth considering a "strip" of tiles created by following such a loop, since that will determine a lot of aspects.  In all three cases, note that the matching rule defined by the loop relies on the loop not crossing the edge at its center; if we pick a direction for the loop, one type of tile will always turn left and the other type will always turn right.  Therefore, providing that both types of tiles are used in the loop, such a strip will have two components to its boundary such that each component only consists of edges of one type of tile (though we may have "slit" edges that have $0$-radian angles).

In particular, we want to think about the dart edges on P2 loops.  To do this, it's worth having [the vertex figures](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Penrose_vertex_figures.svg) handy.

We can start by thinking about a green loop (other than the one implied by the sun vertex).  Note that the "dart-edge boundary" will consist entirely of those edges with red loops; in particular, the reflex angles can always be filled in uniquely with two kites to make aces; once this is done, the sharp angles of each kite will all be part of either jacks (when a pair of darts was separated by two kites in the green loop, and separated by one kite in the red loop) or deuces (when a pair of darts are adjacent in the green loop, and connected by two kites in the red loop).  Furthermore, the two loops meet at every dart in the strip, and the only vertices in one and not the other are precisely the described jack/deuce vertices.

Conversely, with a red loop, every dart must be part of an ace whose tiles all lie in the loop (and whose slit we ignore), and no more than two kites in a row can be visited; each pair of darts is separated by either one kite (in which case the vertex forces a jack with two darts in the corresponding green loop) or two kites (in which case a deuce vertex and a slit is forced, and closed in the corresponding green loop).

The most important fact here, in connecting these two loops, is that *with the darts and one set of the kites forming a loop, the other set of kites and the other loop are all forced*.  The only exception is the sun vertex, which has no darts.

Next, we need to think about composition; here, look at [P2 being composed into P3](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Penrose_tilings_P2_and_P3.svg) and [P3 being composed into P2](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Penrose_tilings_P3_and_P2.svg).

- When P2 is being composed into P3, each dart combines with the two half-kites of its ace to make a thick rhomb, and the remaining half-kites all form thin rhombs by gluing along their bases.  The red loops will cross through the exact same set of rhombs as the pink loops on the rhombs themselves.
- When P3 is being composed into P2, the pink-looped obtuse angle of each thin rhomb will always be in a vertex with two thick rhombs such that their half-thick-rhombs combine with the thin rhomb to form a kite, and the other half-thick-rhombs will combine along their pink-looped legs to form darts.  The pink loops will cross through the same tiles as corresponding *green* loops.

This gives us a nice cycle between the three different types of loops.

1. Start with a *green* loop with $D$ darts and $K$ kites.  Note that if $D \ne 0$, then $K$ must be even, by the jack/deuce vertex property of the sharp angles of the dart.
2. Cross to the corresponding *red* loop, still with $D$ darts, but with $2D-K/2$ kites. Note that all these are forced, so if one loop has a particular type of symmetry, so does the sequence of vertices, and so does the other loop.
3. Compose the *red* loop into a *pink* loop of $D$ thick rhombs and $(2D-K/2)-D=D-K/2$ thin rhombs.
4. Compose the *pink* loop into a *green* loop of $K':=D-K/2$ kites and $D':=D-(D-K/2)=K/2$ darts.
5. Note that $2D'+K'=K+D-K/2=(2D+K)/2$; furthermore, if $2D+K$ is odd, it must be $5$ and the loop must be around the sun vertex.  This fixes it to be of the form $5 \cdot 2^n$ for some $n$, where $n$ represents the number of composition/vertex-force sequences necessary to reach the sun.
6. Though it isn't strictly necessary for the proof, note that $K'-D'=-(K-D)$ represents a sort of turning number; the forced tiles will alternate between the outside and the inside of the loop.
7. Every loop will derive from *de*composition of the sun, and the desired $D_5$ symmetry follows from induction.

I still need to think some to get the actual proof for infinite curves but I think there's an argument that a tile can only be part of such a strip for an infinite curve in one way, but repeated composition will make them inevitably intersect nontrivially.